# TypeScript throws error for not being able to find a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, deprecated

I have a Node.js express application that is serving an Apollo GraphQL API serving as a BFF for a React Application.

The project uses the latest `graphql` npm package of `16.8.0` and it utilizes the `graphql-contstraint-directive` package.

Now when I build my project -- build script is `"build": "tsc"` -- it throws this error:

```
node_modules/graphql-constraint-directive/index.d.ts:3:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-core' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import {PluginDefinition} from "apollo-server-core";
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in node_modules/graphql-constraint-directive/index.d.ts:3
```

Looking at the latest package in Github [here](https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive/blob/c2201f2f1cced4658f3a88017496ea1ece2ac2b8/apollo4.js), it looks to be using the `PluginDefinition` from [`apollo-server-core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-core) which is deprecated. In addition, the `package.json` file does not seem to add the `apollo-server-core` as a dependency, which is strange. (refer [here](https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive/blob/c2201f2f1cced4658f3a88017496ea1ece2ac2b8/package.json)).

Has anybody run into this issue before ? If so, how did you solve it ? I guess I could try installing the deprecated `apollo-server-core` package but that does not seem right.

Any help is appreciacted.

Comment: This should solve the issue temporarily, thank you for sharing this !